# Why megamenu overlaping on boxed body?

Tags: jquery, css, menu

Can anybody please tell me why the mega menu overlaping on boxed body?
[Mega menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEtec.png)

Thanks

Comment: because you mega menu is not boxed that is why

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: how can you do what?